# Unable to mount docker folder into host using docker-compose

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using a docker container to run cucumber test, after the test finished it will generate a report, I want to copy the report to my host machine.
Have a report folder at the root of my project and create a test folder in Dockerfile and copy all the files into the container.
**Expect: copy reports from container's /test/report folder to host's /report folder**
docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
  build:
    context: .
    args:
        xx : "xxx"
  volumes:
  - ./report:/test/report
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /test
WORKDIR /test
COPY . /test
RUN /test/testing.sh
```

have other configuration in Dockerfile but not related to volume/mount, so didn't post it here.

There should be three reports in the report folder.
Inside the container, the reports can be seen at /test/report after the test, and if the /report in my host not null, it will override the reports in the container. But the volume doesn't work in reverse order.
Running this on a windows machine currently.

Comment: Please try using volumes, Docker recommends to use volumes instead of mounts in Windows environments.

Comment: @Aak Hi, I'm using volumes, have updated the description

Comment: You should write only the name of the volume and not prepend it with any `/` or `.`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a bind mount.
Also it is normally best to post your whole docker-compose file just so it's easier to debug/reproduce/help.

Try explicitly setting the volume as a bind mount and see how you go:

```
- type: bind
  source: ./report
  target: /test/report
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

Comment: doesn't work :(  i updated the description and add more details

Comment: I've tested it both ways and it seems to work fine from my end?
>ls report/

>docker exec -it container touch /test/report/boo

>ls report/
boo

>

Comment: my docker container will stop after the test finish, I tried to add ```ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"] ``` at the end of Dockerfile and go through /test/report folder, the reports were generated prorperly inside the container. But the report in /report folder in my host machine did not be updated.